# How to get all months in a query that has no matches?

Tags: google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

My current output looks like this where I filtered out the result with only one SKU in my query.

[image: Current Output]

I want to display results like the below image

[image]

So I tweaked my query a little bit but only got results like this

[image]

what should I do to display SKU as well, I don't want the Null value in the SKU column.

**current query written so far**

```sql
month_agg as
(select sku_number, extract(month from date_) as month, sum(v) as viewed, sum(a) as add_to_cart, sum(p) as purchased
           from merge_and_pivot
          where sku_number = '10671924'
          group by sku_number, 2 order by 1,2)
, month_generate as
(SELECT extract(month from date_) as month
            FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-01-01', '2018-12-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS date_)
select a.month, b.sku_number, coalesce(b.viewed, 0) , coalesce(b.add_to_cart, 0), coalesce(b.purchased, 0)
from month_generate a
left JOIN  month_agg b on a.month = b.month
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below query

```sql
SELECT month,
       MAX(sku_number) OVER() sku_number, -- assuming all sku_number is same
       COALESCE(viewed, 0) viewed,
       COALESCE(add_to_cart, 0) add_to_cart,
       COALESCE(purchased, 0) purchased,
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 12)) month LEFT JOIN sample USING(month)
 ORDER BY month;
```

output:

[image]

with sample:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample AS
SELECT '10671924' sku_number, 1 month, 9 viewed, 6 add_to_cart, 0 purchased UNION ALL
SELECT '10671924', 10, 32, 8, 0 UNION ALL
SELECT '10671924', 11, 948, 688, 163 UNION ALL
SELECT '10671924', 12, 630, 299, 83;
```

Updated Query :

```sql
SELECT month,
       sku.sku_number,
       COALESCE(viewed, 0) viewed,
       COALESCE(add_to_cart, 0) add_to_cart,
       COALESCE(purchased, 0) purchased,
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sku_number FROM sample) sku, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 12)) month
  LEFT JOIN sample USING(sku_number, month)
 ORDER BY sku_number, month;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I have 450k different SKU, it is just that I filtered out 1 SKU just to show

Comment: I thinks you can modify the query to add more requirements.  If you have to consider multiple **SKU**,  it'd better to generate all the possible **(sku_number, month)** combinations first and do **LEFT JOIN** with your table.  I've updated query, so kindly checkt that out.